# java.util.concurrent code review

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-management

I'm study `java.util.concurrent` library and find many *infinite* loops in the source code, like this one

```
//java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger by Doug Lea
public final int getAndSet(int newValue) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        if (compareAndSet(current, newValue))
            return current;
    }
}
```

I wonder, in what cases actual value can not be equal to the expected value (in this case `compareAndSet` returns false)?

Comment: It is not really "infinite" because the probability that other threads keep "infinitely" modifying the value right after your *get()* and right before your *compareAndSet()* is so low that it is not a concern.  The probably of winning the national lottery the day you are struck by lightning is higher than that of the loop you wrote being infinite.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, you probably don't play in the national lottery)

Comment: @Stats, I'd strongly advise to read some theory. here is some beginner friendly article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/

Comment: @bestsss, thanks. I allready start reading Concurrency in practice. And during some test find this understandable (for me) code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the value is modified in another thread, the get() and compareAndSet() can see different values. This is the sort of thing a concurrent library needs to worry about.

Comment: Performance, creating locks, or using `volatile` declaration requires due to the visibility constraint that changes are flushed into memory to guarantee that all threads see the same result.

Comment: @Johan Sjöberg, in `AtomicInteger` value already `volatile`. Will it cost less to use such vatiable as monitor?

Comment: The point of lock-free operations is that they cost less than locks/monitors.

Comment: @Johan, Yeah.. I mean, if we have two variables. One of them are already with `volatile` declaration. If we will create monitor from any of this variable we will lose some perfomance. Will it depends from what variable will use as monitore?

Comment: There is no need to make a monitor on a volatile variable, and even if you did, it would likely not matter the least.

Comment: @Stas, A synchronized lock costs between 500 and 2000 ns even with low contention. This is in part due to calls which go all the way to the OS level. (If you have a virtual machine, its much worse)  A spin lock like this costs between 2 and 30 ns. (this is because it just uses the CPUs built in support for these operations)

Comment: get() and compareAndSet() look like method calls, but when compiled to native code they are turned into machine code instructions.

Answer (score 10):

Many modern CPUs have `compareAndSet()` map to an atomic hardware operation. That means, it is threadsafe without requiring synchronization (which is a relatively expensive operation in comparison). However, it's only `compareAndSet()` itself with is atomic, so in order to `getAndSet()` (i.e. set the variable to a given value and return the value it had at that time, without the possibility of it being set to a different value in between) the code uses a trick: first it gets the value, then it attempts `compareAndSet()` with the value it just got and the new value. If that fails, the variable was manipulated by another thread inbetween, and the code tries again.

This is faster than using synchronization if `compareAndSet()` fails rarely, i.e. if there are not too many threads writing to the variable at the same time. In an extreme case where many threads are writing to the variable at all times, synchronization can actually be faster because while there is an overhead to synchronize, other threads trying to access the variable will wait and be woken up when it's their turn, rather than having to retry the operation repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* an infinite loop, it is good practice when dealing with a TAS (test and set) algorithm. What the loop does is (a) read from memory (should be volatile semantics) (b) compute a new value (c) write the new value *if the old value has not in the meantime changed*.

In database land this is known as optimistic locking. It leverages the fact that most concurrent updates to shared memory are uncontended, and in that case, this is the cheapest possible way to do it.

In fact, this is basically what an unbiased Lock will do in the uncontended case. It will read the value of the lock, and if it is unlocked, it will do a CAS of the thread ID and if that succeeds, the lock is now held. If it fails, someone else got the lock first. Locks though deal with the failure case in a much more sophisticated way than merely retrying the op over and over again. They'll keep reading it for a little while incase the lock is quickly unlocked (spin-locking) then usually go to sleep for bit to let other threads in until their turn (exponential back-off).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an actual usage of the `compareAndSet` operation: Imagine that you design an algorithm that calculates something in multiple threads.

Each thread remembers an old value and based on it performs a complicated calculation.

Then it wants to set the new result ONLY if the old value hasn't been already changed by another calculation thread. If the old value is not the expected one the thread discards its own work, takes a new value and restarts the calculations. It uses `compareAndSet` for that.

Further other threads are guaranteed to get only fresh values to continue the calculations.

The "infinite" loops are used to implement "busy waiting" which might be much less expensive than putting the thread to sleep especially when the thread contention is low.

Cheers!